# MariaDB suddenly stops working (after checking for insecure accounts), why does this happen?

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-22.04

I'm running a virtual server with some hobby site and recently migrated to Ubuntu 22.04 plus MariaDB as replacement for MySQL.

It all seemed to run fine until I got random database connection issues. It runs fine for hours and suddenly just stops working.

After a reboot, it runs fine again....until it goes bust again randomly hours later.

When I output the database status, I get this:

[image]

Current MariaDB version:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.7-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Does anyone have a clue why it suddenly exits and stops working?

Comment: The log says: "this unit has been killed by the OOM killer" which means processes on this server consumed more than the physical RAM, and Linux decided to abort the process using the greatest amount of RAM, which was the MariaDB Server process. It could be that MariaDB was overallocated, or it could be that other processes were consuming RAM at the same time.

Comment: This question appears not to be about a coding problem, and it's not necessarily the fault of MariaDB at all, so it probably belongs on https://askubuntu.com.

Comment: @BillKarwin Your clue actually really helped! I discovered I made a stupid mistake of not setting up swap memory as I already anticipated the physical allocated RAM could be insufficient with some peaks while I was setting up the new VM. I just forgot to set it up for some reason. Just fixed it.

Comment: Okay, but in my experience, swap is super bad for database servers. Your database performance will plummet if the server actually uses swap. We even deliberately disabled swap on our database servers.

Comment: It's actually not swapping aggressively. I never saw performance really plumit as the server mostly serves relatively static content and a majority of the requests is just cached responses. Only an occasional peak in load should be sustained by not running out of memory.

I do agree using swap memory for heavy (production) database purposes isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) solved the problem. The OOM killer indicated that it ran out of physical memory. I couldn't grasp why as I had swap plenty of swap memory. The problem: I only forgot to set it up on the new VM while migrating.

Swap configured and good to go again.